# Use an array to search element for data-attribute and hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to search through a class for elements that have data-id attribute that matches in the array, and hide them.

The HTML:

```
<li class="list" data-id="1">one</li>
<li class="list" data-id="2">two</li>
<li class="list" data-id="3">three</li>
<li class="list" data-id="4">four</li>
```

I have an array: 
`var dataIDcheck = ['1', '3']`

Any ideas on how I can search through the class .list and hide 1 and 3 (or whatever is in the array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dataIDcheck = ['1', '3'];
$('[data-id="' + dataIDcheck.join('"], [data-id="') + '"]').hide();
```

http://jsbin.com/ojipaw/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) function

```
 $('.list').filter(function(){
      return $.inArray($(this).data('id'),dataIDcheck) > -1
 }).hide(); // <-- hides any elements that have data-id found in array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids   = [1, 3],
    count = ids.length,
    parts = [];

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    parts.push('[data-id="' + ids[i] + '"]');
}

var selector = parts.join(',');

var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
```

This works with standard DOM (IE8+) and does not need any libraries. It also may make sense for you to see [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) documentation.

Comment: Is that using the array or specifying [data-id="1"], [data-id="3"]?

Comment: You can easily construct selector manually using any number of any ids. I've added more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (id in dataIDcheck) {
    $('.list[data-id=' + dataIDcheck[id] + ']').hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not jquery's [inArray()](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.inArray)

```
var dataIDcheck = [1, 3];


$('.list').each(function() {
    if($.inArray($(this).data("id"),dataIDcheck) > -1) {
      $(this).fadeOut(); 
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZvB8/)
​